# Android animator versus anim resource directories

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm doing some research in utilizing Android's resource directories appropriately and the following isn't clear to me:

What is the difference between the android animator resource directory and the android anim resource directory?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Moreover I guess the question I'm asking is what is the difference between property animations and tween animations?

Comment: I didn't see this answered below, so from the API guide link below, at the very bottom, it says "To distinguish animation files that use the new property animation APIs from those that use the legacy view animation framework, starting with Android 3.1, you should save the XML files for property animations in the res/animator/ directory."

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I honestly think Google have done a very good job explaining the differences in their [Property Animations API guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) (see below).

TL;DR the main differences are:

1. Tween animations are succinct and allow for the manipulation of no more than the location (translation), size (scale), angle (rotation) and translucency (alpha) of **views**. The property animations framework is more generic and flexible: It generalizes the former case by allowing for real-time updating of any property (e.g. "foobar") of animations' target-object -- provided it has a setFoobar() method. setScaleX(), setAlpha(), etc. are just a specific case when it comes to views.
2. Accordingly, implementing tween animations is often easier and the code is more lightweight.
3. Property animations can be used over target objects of any type, not just views: the only thing that matters is the definition of setFoobar() methods as explained earlier (reflection based method look-up).
4. Tween animations merely perform adjustments over views' configurations, while property animations effectively modify the object. A common flaw of the former approach is that when using animations for moving views around, the associated clickable area doesn't get updated throughout the animation and gets out-of-sync with the view's effective location on the screen.

To quote from the guide:

> **How Property Animation Differs from View Animation**
>
> The view animation system provides the capability to only animate View objects, so if you wanted to animate non-View objects, you have to implement your own code to do so. The view animation system is also constrained in the fact that it only exposes a few aspects of a View object to animate, such as the scaling and rotation of a View but not the background color, for instance.
>
> Another disadvantage of the view animation system is that it only modified where the View was drawn, and not the actual View itself. For instance, if you animated a button to move across the screen, the button draws correctly, but the actual location where you can click the button does not change, so you have to implement your own logic to handle this.
>
> With the property animation system, these constraints are completely removed, and you can animate any property of any object (Views and non-Views) and the object itself is actually modified. The property animation system is also more robust in the way it carries out animation. At a high level, you assign animators to the properties that you want to animate, such as color, position, or size and can define aspects of the animation such as interpolation and synchronization of multiple animators.
>
> The view animation system, however, takes less time to setup and requires less code to write. If view animation accomplishes everything that you need to do, or if your existing code already works the way you want, there is no need to use the property animation system. It also might make sense to use both animation systems for different situations if the use case arises.

Answer (score 20):

Basically **Tween animations** are standard animation,

for eg: Scale, Rotate, Translate, etc. (These can be applied to any type of views)

Where are **Property Animations** as the name suggest are used to change the Property of any View.

For eg: Changing Alpha of ImageView, in lollipop changing translationZ value of fab button, etc.

Hope that clarifies.

[Check Android View Tween Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html#tween-animation)

> A tween animation can perform a series of simple transformations (position, size, rotation, and transparency) on the contents of a View object. So, if you have a TextView object, you can move, rotate, grow, or shrink the text. If it has a background image, the background image will be transformed along with the text. The animation package provides all the classes used in a tween animation.

[check this url for Property Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)

> The property animation system is a robust framework that allows you to animate almost anything. You can define an animation to change any object property over time, regardless of whether it draws to the screen or not. A property animation changes a property's (a field in an object) value over a specified length of time. To animate something, you specify the object property that you want to animate, such as an object's position on the screen, how long you want to animate it for, and what values you want to animate between.

Comment: Thanks! This was very concise, I totally understand now!

Answer (score 18):

Try this shorter answer:

**res/anim** -
Any view [Tween Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html#tween-animation) (*scale, rotate, translate*).

**res/animator** - 
Certain views [Property Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) (*ImageView - change alpha, FAB - set Z-order*).